# CEF Browser issue with window forms application

Tags: winforms, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

Issue with login.live.com

[image: issue with login.live.com- click here for issue]

as I was working with the CEF Browser in my windows application when it comes login page it was working fine in local Visual studio, but after installing app using wix installer only login page showing like above link(shrinking). I was wondering what could be the cause for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you browser settings is default you must move folder "locales" in your folder app.

Comment: @JampalaUday Mark my answer as true